# CSS bulletpoints between multiple logos

Tags: html, css

I have a set of logos within a `<div>`. The code looks like the follow and it's available at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ueLFM/).

**CSS**

```
@font-face {
    font-family:'JustVectorRegular';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    src: url('fonts/justvector/justvector-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/justvector/justvector-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('eot'), url('fonts/justvector/justvector-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/justvector/justvector-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/justvector/justvector-webfont.svg#webfontmuk63VQd') format('svg');
}
.social {
    padding:0;
    margin:2em 0;
    list-style:none;
    text-align: center;
}
.social li {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0;
    margin-bottom: -3px;
}
.social li a {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin: 0 .1em .2em 0;
    line-height:100%;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:'JustVectorRegular';
    font-size:32px;
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 10px;
    min-width:27px;
    max-height:28px;
    color:#444;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="social">
    <img src="images/mine/logo.png" style="width: 75px; height: 75px;" />
    <i class="icon-remove"></i>
    <img src="images/mine/logo.png" style="width: 75px; height: 75px;" />
    <i class="icon-remove"></i>
    <img src="images/mine/logo.png" style="width: 75px; height: 75px;" />
    <i class="icon-remove"></i>
    <img src="images/mine/logo.png" style="width: 75px; height: 75px;" />
    <i class="icon-remove"></i>
    <img src="images/mine/logo.png" style="width: 75px; height: 75px;" />
    <i class="icon-remove"></i>
    <img src="images/mine/logo.png" style="width: 75px; height: 75px;" />
    <i class="icon-remove"></i>
    <img src="images/mine/logo.png" style="width: 75px; height: 75px;" />
</ul>
```

I want to break them up by putting in a bullet point in between each one, but as the code describes it wraps the logos according to screen width, and a bullet point at the end of a line looks wrong. I'm looking to make the code insert a bullet point between after each logo, **except** the one at the end of a row.

Is this possible? I'm really stuck and can't find any help on this

thanks :)

(and apologies if i haven't got the lingo right - all quite new to me)

Comment: Can you add your HTML? And, possibly, a (representative/[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) showing what you've got so far?

Comment: will do. excuse the speed, all this is new to me. it's on its way.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ueLFM/ - can't get the bulletpoint loading. unsure how to load font into a jsfiddle

Comment: how is this representative of your code? css targets list items and anchor elements, neither of which are in your markup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `:before` pseudoelement for each element except for first one:

```
LI + LI:before {content: "*"; }
```

Comment: sorry - not quite what i'm after. maybe i wasn't clear in my question, although looksing at the ':after' could work, as long as i could stop it on the final one of the row. thanks anyway :)

Comment: Visual result of something before each element except for first one is similar to result of something after each element except for last one. Advantage of using `:before` is that it will work in IE8 that does not support `:last-child` pseudoclass. If IE8 does not matter for you, you can use `LI:after {content: "*"; }` and `LI:last-child {content: normal; }`.